# Tweaking Pandas dataframe to train a regression (advance prediction of events) model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

My dataframe has several prediction variable columns and a target (event) column. The events are either `1` (the event occurred) or `0` (no event). There could be consecutive events that make the target column `1` for the consecutive timestamp. I want to shift (backward) all rows in the dataframe when an event occurs and delete all rows starting from the original event occurrence timestamp (row) to the newly shifted timestamp (row). In other words, I don't want my ML model to see the rows corresponding to recent timestamps (shifted amount of rows) when the event occurred. The event occurrence pattern (as seen in the data plot) should be the same on the original and the tweaked dataframe (if possible). Following is the sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17],
    'C': [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34]
})
```

I used the following [method](https://github.com/cran2367/autoencoder_classifier/blob/master/autoencoder_classifier.ipynb) to shift the dataframe. Note that this method is for classification problems.

```
sign = lambda x: (1, -1)[x < 0]
def curve_shift(df, shift_by):
    vector = df['A'].copy()
    for s in range(abs(shift_by)):
        tmp = vector.shift(sign(shift_by))
        tmp = tmp.fillna(0)
        vector += tmp
    labelcol = 'A'
    # Add vector to the df
    df.insert(loc=0, column=labelcol+'tmp', value=vector)
    # Remove the rows with labelcol == 1.
    df = df.drop(df[df[labelcol] == 1].index)
    # Drop labelcol and rename the tmp col as labelcol
    df = df.drop(labelcol, axis=1)
    df = df.rename(columns={labelcol+'tmp': labelcol})
    # Make the labelcol binary
    df.loc[df[labelcol] > 0, labelcol] = 1
    return df
```

The above method shifts all rows of dataframe based on the target column (Column `'A'` in my case), fills the shifted rows in the target column with `1`, and deletes the original row that had target `1`. In my case, I want to delete those rows.

I added one more method to delete all the duplicate `1s` if they appear consecutive after `curve_shift` as follows.

```
def delete_duplicate_ones(df): 
    '''
    This function detects consecutive 1s in the 'A' column 
    and delete the rows corresponding to all but the first 1 in 
    each group of consecutive 1s.
    '''
    mask = df['A'] == 1
    duplicates = mask & mask.shift(-1)
    df = df[~duplicates.shift().fillna(False)]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    return df
```

But it does not solve my problem. The `delete_duplicate_ones` method deletes all consecutive duplicates irrespective of consecutiveness in the original data or created by the `curve_shfit` method. If the event occurs at the `nth` row, I want to shift the target by `m` rows (`shfit_by` args in `curve_shift`)backward and delete all rows between `n` and `n-m` (row `n` inclusive). I want the ML model to see the target occurrence before it actually occurs in the original dataset, and never see the original prediction variable present at `shift_by` rows.

Following are the plots of data:

**Original**:

[image]

**After `curve_shift` by `-2`**:

[image]

**After `delete_deplicate_ones`**:

[image]

Comment: "*But it does not solve my problem*" what is the expected output that matches the provided input?

Comment: Hi @mozway, 
The expected output is a shifted dataframe (whose target pattern is the same as the original) and all rows (number determined by shifted_by value) that appear before the event occurrence are deleted.

Comment: Please provide the **explicit expected output** as a DataFrame constructor like you did for the input. A description is ambiguous, a DataFrame is not (or less).

Comment: I see you added some details, but still not the expected output. Is there an issue?